# Having a UINavigation in a UISplitView

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

So I was looking at this app http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pageonce-personal-finance/id285056092?mt=8 (see iPad screenshots) and it appears that they have a uinavigation controller within the Details view of the UISplitView. When I tried to make a UINavigation controller in my Details View, the navigation bar overlaps with the UISplitView top bar. For example, on the pageonce app, my blue navigation bar would overlap with the top, silver bar.

Is that blue bar a navigation controller, or something else? If so, how did they move the navigation bar down while still having access to the top bar? Can we control the position of the navigation bar/view?

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [apple.com](http://a1.phobos.apple.com/us/r1000/008/Purple/b3/f3/77/mzl.afchmopq.480x480-75.jpg))</sub>
.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have a nested UINavigationController inside a UINavigationController on both the master and detail views. Each UINavigationController creates a bar. There is no such thing as a "UISplitView top bar". You only get a top bar if you put a UINavigationController inside the UISplitViewController in the first place. So all you need to do is to put another UINavigationController inside the UINavigationController and you will get another bar.